# Unable to Read a Text File via BufferedReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am unable to read a text file via a `BufferedReader` Object. However I can successfully write to the same text file via a `BufferedWriter` Object.

The intent of my program is to read a text file called `queryCountFile.txt` which will then able to figure out how many `Query` Objects (my custom object) have been previously created. From there, I will then be able to create as many `Query` Objects as a want while being able to keep track of the number of said Queries.

The function that tries (and fails) to read from the text file is called `findNumberOfQueries()`. It is located in my file called **Query.java**

Can anyone understand why I am unable to read from the text file?

**QuickControllerApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class QuickControllerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuickControllerApplication.class, args);
        //everthing below this line is for testing purposes
        Query littleQuery = new Query(101L);
        //littleQuery.testPrint();
        littleQuery.generateQueryID();
        System.out.println(littleQuery.findNumberOfQueries());
    }
}
```

**Query.java**

```
/**************************************************************
 * queryIDNumber - a long that holds the individual data of an
 * individual query. Each query will have a unique number
 * associated with it.
 **************************************************************/
public class Query {
    final Long MIN_ID_NUMBER = 1L;  //minimum ID Number that can be ever generated by the program
    final String QUERY_COUNT_FILE = "queryCountFile.txt";       //this file will simply hold a number that states how many queries have been created
    final int SKIP_NUM_LINES_IN_FILE = 2;   //the first X number of lines that will skipped in QUERY_COUNT_FILE

    //final Long MAX_ID_NUMBER = 9223372036854775807L; //maximum ID Number that can be ever generated by the program

    private Long queryID;           //each query must have a unique ID Number which will go in the URL when the user is viewing the result of the query search.
    private static Long totalQueryIDs = 0L;      //holds the value of how many queries have been created over the life of the program

    public Query(Long previouslyGeneratedIDNumber)
    {
        generateQueryID();
        //totalQueryIDs++;
        //OTHER FUNCTION CALLS
        //WILL PROBABLY GO
        //HERE LATER...
    }

/**************************************************************
 * generateQueryID - Generate a ID Number for a query. ID
 * Number must be unique, and then is assigned to queryID
 **************************************************************/
public void generateQueryID(){
    Long generatedNumber;

    //Finds the totalQueryIDs stored in QUERY_COUNT_FILE
    generatedNumber = findNumberOfQueries();

    if (generatedNumber <= MIN_ID_NUMBER){
        totalQueryIDs = MIN_ID_NUMBER;
    }
    else {
        totalQueryIDs = generatedNumber + 1L;
    }

    queryID = totalQueryIDs;
}
/**************************************************************
     * findNumberOfQueries - This function finds out how many
     * queries have been generated so far. This function will check
     * a text file that will contain the past number of queries
     * that have been generated.
     **************************************************************/
    public Long findNumberOfQueries(){
        //Check a file. If queryCountFile.txt is not found then numberOfQueries is considered 0 and becomes 1?
        try {
            Date date = new Date();
            //Assume default encoding.
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(QUERY_COUNT_FILE);
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(QUERY_COUNT_FILE);

            //Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            //Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            bufferedWriter.write("FILE LAST WRITTEN TO ON: " + date + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.write("totalQueryIDs:\n");
            bufferedWriter.write("5");

            //reading from QUERY_COUNT_FILE
            try{
                System.out.println("got here\n");   //debug statement
                String line;    //temp var

                //skip first SKIP_NUM_LINES_IN_FILE lines in QUERY_COUNT_FILE
                for (int count = 0; count < SKIP_NUM_LINES_IN_FILE; count++) {
                    bufferedReader.readLine();
                }

                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    System.out.println("stuff bufferedReader got: " + line);
                }
            }
            catch(IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error reading to file '" + QUERY_COUNT_FILE + "'");
            }

            //Close the file.
            bufferedWriter.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error writing to file '" + QUERY_COUNT_FILE + "'");
        }
return totalQueryIDs;
}
```

}

Comment: 1. You should flush and close the `Writer` before attempting to read  2. `while (line != null) {` `line` is never re-assigned - if it is not null at this point there will be an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, are correct. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This is old-school reading anyway nio offers method to read all files, or stream lines etc.

Answer (score 2):

Let me suggest you another way of reading your lines using most recent APIs method which make it easier to read and maintain (at least in my opinion) :

```
try(final Stream<String> fileStream = Files.lines(Paths.get("queryCountFile.txt")){
    fileStream.skip(SKIP_NUM_LINES_IN_FILE)
              .forEach(line -> processMyLine(line));
}
```

For completeness, the problem in your example is that you never re-assign `line` variable in your loop :

```
while(line != null)
```

should be :

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
```

Comment: Based on your code, `processMyLine()` is a custom function. But what exactly is it doing? Is this a function were you call `System.out.println()` and other related functions if one so desires?

Comment: @lordmichael95 It does whatever you want it to do - it is your role to create it. Basically, this is a function that you will create which will receive a line (as a `String`) as parameter. You can put anything you want in it. Though if all you want is to print the line, you can replace `line -> processMyLine(line)` with `System.out::println`. Also, if `processMyLine` is in the same class, you can also change `line -> processMyLine(line)` for `this::processMyLine` if you want it cleaner (I personally do). If you want to print with a custom message as in your actual code [...]

Comment: [...] you can use the lambda syntax : `line -> System.out.println("stuff bufferedReader got: " + line)`.